# Can this extend to infinity case?

Tags: real-analysis

[image: Uniformly Integrable]

In this proposition about uniformly integrable, can we extend to infinity case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $E=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and define $f_n=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$.

Comment: can we add some conditions to make it right?

Comment: If $E$ is a probability space, then a sequence $\{f_n\}$ which is bounded in $L^p$ for some $p>1$ will be uniformly integrable. The existence of a dominating $L^1$ function is also sufficient to guarantee uniform integrability.